# Change volume in CMD/Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, volume

I am making a batch-file that will start a song and i want to make it ask for a volume.

How do I set the volume?
Is it even possible?

Comment: to start a song, you need a external utility (I assume, you are using one) Look into the documentation for command line parameters (or at least tell us what utility you use)

Comment: I start it with the start-command. I know how to do that but how do i change the volume on my computer?

Comment: yes. You start it with `start whateverutilty.exe`. There might be some parameters to the utility to set the volume. You will find them in the documentation of the utiltiy. There is no cmd-built-in-functionality for anything related to sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Batch file "ask for a volume", execute: `sndvol.exe` (`sndvol32.exe` in Windows XP).

There is no way that a Batch file "set the volume" via standard commands, but a third party program can do it, like [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)